# Não consigo chamar modal de erro sem dar clique (Materialize)

Tags: php, css, materialize

Não consigo chamar o modal sem ter que clicar no botão. Eu gostaria de que um modal aparecesse de acordo com o "VerificarDisponibilidade"
Caso retorne true = aparecer modal com mensagem de que foi cadastrado com sucesso
Caso retorne false = modal dizendo que deu erro.

```
 if (!empty($_POST['nome_prova'])){
        $prova = ($_POST['nome_prova']);
        $data_prova = explode('/',($_POST['data_prova']));
        $requerente = ($_POST['requerente']);
        $num_acessos = ($_POST['numero']);

        $data_prova = $data_prova[2].'-'.$data_prova[1].'-'.$data_prova[0];

        if ($reservas->VerificarDisponibilidade($prova, $data_prova, $requerente, $num_acessos)){
            $reservas->reservar($prova, $data_prova, $requerente, $num_acessos);
            MODAL DE SUCESSO AQUI
        } else {  
            ?>
             MODAL DE ERRO AQUI 
            <?php
     }

}

?>

 <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal  modal-trigger">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta dessa maneira

```
<?

    if (!empty($_POST['nome_prova'])){
        $prova = ($_POST['nome_prova']);
        $data_prova = explode('/',($_POST['data_prova']));
        $requerente = ($_POST['requerente']);
        $num_acessos = ($_POST['numero']);

        $data_prova = $data_prova[2].'-'.$data_prova[1].'-'.$data_prova[0];

        if ($reservas->VerificarDisponibilidade($prova, $data_prova, $requerente, $num_acessos)){
            $reservas->reservar($prova, $data_prova, $requerente, $num_acessos);
?>
           <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#modal1").modal();
        });
    </script>
        <? } else {  
            ?>
             <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#modal2").modal();
        });
    </script>
            <?php
     }

}

?>

 <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal  modal-trigger">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Bom dia Lucas, muito obrigado por tentar ajudar! Mas mesmo assim não consegui. O modal simplesmente não abre. Quando eu o ponho pra abrir clicando no botão abre normalmente. Então descartei algo relacionado ao js do materialize. Realmente não estou conseguindo abri-lo com decisão ao invés de clicar em botão

Comment: Troca o .modal(); por .modal('open'); ou .modal('show');